# How to display Terminal results in textView field on Cocoa Applescript application

Tags: macos, cocoa, terminal, applescript

I am developing a Cocoa Applescript application using Xcode 7. This application will run simple Terminal commands such as $ cd, $ ls, $ ./name, etc., etc.

My question is how do I display Terminal results (such as when I type "ls" it shows me the list of contents of my current directory) in a textView field within the GUI window.

[screenshot of my simple application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8cSk.png)

```
script AppDelegate

    property parent : class "NSObject"

    -- IBOutlets
    property theWindow : missing value

on changedirectoryClicked_(sender)
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "cd"
        end tell
    end changedirectoryClicked_

on ifconfigClicked_(sender)
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "ifconfig"
    end tell
end ifconfigClicked_

on exitClicked_(sender)
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "exit"
    end tell
end exitClicked_

on lsClicked_(sender)
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "cd"
    end tell
end lsClicked_

    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
            -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
            -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
            return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_
```

end script

Answer (score 1):

I have a few questions to understand what part of this flow you do not know how to accomplish. Are you intentionally wanting to open a Terminal window?
Normally, to get the the return result from a shell command in order to feed it to a textView, you need to use the "do shell script" applescript command.

```
on lsClicked:sender
    set theResult to do shell script "ls"
    setTextView(theResult)
end lsClicked:
```

Note that you'll have to pipe and cd changes along with the ls command inside the do shell script command.

Comment: I am wanting to click on a button in order to run a Terminal command. I then want the results of said terminal commands to display in my texView field within my GUI. I actually would prefer for the Terminal window to remain hidden, I would not want the Desktop overwhelmed with windows.

Comment: well, this example will do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, first you need to make a property under theWindow for the text field and connect it:

```
property myTextField : missing value -- Connect to Text Field
```

Now to return the terminal results into a textfield you do:

```
on chooseDirectory_(sender)
    set choosenDirectory to (choose folder with prompt "choose a directory to list")
end chooseDirectory_
```

We also need to add a directory convert to change the AppleScript Directory to Terminal,
Under "set choosenDirectory etc.." , Add the following:

```
set choosenDirectory2 to POSIX path of (choosenDirectory)
set amountOfCharactersOfChoosenDirectory to count the characters of choosenDirectory2
set choosenDirectory3 to ""
set currentCharacterOfChoosenDirectory to 0
repeat amountOfCharactersOfChoosenDirectory times
    set currentCharacterOfChoosenDirectory to currentCharacterOfChoosenDirectory + 1
    set currentLetterOfChoosenDirectory to character currentCharacterOfChoosenDirectory of choosenDirectory2
    if currentLetterOfChoosenDirectory is " " then
        set choosenDirectory3 to choosenDirectory3 & "' '"
    else
        set choosenDirectory3 to choosenDirectory3 & currentLetterOfChoosenDirectory
    end if
end repeat
```

Ok Now we can run the terminal command:

```
set theOutput to (do shell script "ls " & choosenDirectory3)
```

Finally we can write it in the Text box:

```
tell myTextField to setStringValue_(theOutput)
```

Sorry, this is a bit advanced but this might help